# Is there a way to make a log 2d histogram in plotly?

Tags: ipython, plotly

Is there a way to make a log 2d histogram in plotly? I'm not sure if this is even possible.

Here is the matplotlib code that worked:

```
%matplotlib inline
import math
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

print len(list_length_view)
%time xy = [(math.log10(x[0]), math.log10(x[1])) for x in list_length_view if x[0] > 0 and x[1] > 0]
print len(xy)
## Why are there negative lengths or view counts!?!?

plt.hist2d([x[0] for x in list_length_view], [x[1] for x in list_length_view], 
           bins=(40, 60), range=numpy.array([(0, 10000), (0, 1000000)]),
           norm=LogNorm(), cmap='Oranges')
cb1 = plt.colorbar()
plt.gca().set_xlabel(r'Clip Duration in Seconds')
plt.gca().set_ylabel(r'Views Per Clip')
cb1.set_label(r'Total Clips')
```

[image]

However, my original goal was to do it in plotly. Here is the code I tried to use so far to get it to work:

```
data4 = Data([
    Histogram2d(
        x=[x[0] for x in list_length_view], #Durations of highlights
        y=[y[1] for y in list_length_view], # Views fo hgihlights
        nbinsx=10,
        nbinsy=10,
        )])

layout4 = dict(
   title='Public Highlight Analysis',
   yaxis=YAxis(
       title = 'Average Number of Views'),
   xaxis1=XAxis(
       title = "Duration of Highlight in Seconds")
   )
fig3 = Figure(data=data4, layout=layout4)
py.iplot(fig3)
```

[image]

I also tried converting matplotlib to plotly.

```
def plot_mpl_fig():
    xy = [(math.log10(x[0]), math.log10(x[1])) for x in list_length_view if x[0] > 0 and x[1] > 0]
    plt.hist2d([x[0] for x in xy], [x[1] for x in xy], 
               bins=200, range=numpy.array([(-1, 4), (-1, 6)]),
               norm=LogNorm(), cmap='Oranges')
    cb1 = plt.colorbar()
    plt.gca().set_xlabel(r'Log$_{10}$(Clip Duration in Seconds)')
    plt.gca().set_ylabel(r'Log$_{10}$(Views Per Clip)')
    cb1.set_label(r'Total Clips')

plot_mpl_fig()
mpl_fig1 = plt.gcf()
py_fig1 = tls.mpl_to_plotly(mpl_fig1, verbose=True)
```

[image]